# Well-Ordering Irrationality

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, well-orders

Let $D$ be a positive integer and the let the square root of $D$ be a real number. Assuming that the square root of D is not an integer (i.e. $D$ is not a perfect square), use Well-Ordering to prove that there exists some integer $a$ such that $a <  sqrt(D) < a+1.$

My proof attempt begins with assuming that the square root of D is not an integer and letting $a$ be the least integer that satisfies the inequality $a < $sqrt(D)$ < a + 1$, then I'm not sure what to do. My intuition tells me to square both sides, but then how would I proceed with the proof.

Comment: It is not clear from your definition of $a$ (the least integer satisfying $a<\mathit{sqrt}(D)<a+1$) that such $a$ really exists. In fact, that is what you have to prove. Try to find another definition of $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} ~| ~ \sqrt{D} < n \}$.

By the Archimedean property, the set $A$ is not the empty set,
and $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

Thus by the well ordering principle, $A$ has the least element, say $\alpha$.

The assumption for $D$ implies that $D \in \mathbb{N}$ and $D \neq m^2$ for every $m\in \mathbb{N}$.

Thus $D \in \mathbb{N}$ and $D \neq 1^2$, i.e., $D \neq 1$. 
Hence $1<D$, so $1<\sqrt{D}$.

Thus $1 \notin A$.

(If $1 \in A$, then $\sqrt{D}<1$. Contradiction.)

Hence $\alpha$ cannot be $1$, so $\alpha \in \mathbb{N} -\{1\} = \{2,3,4,\ldots\}$.

Thus $\alpha -1 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Because $\alpha$ is the least element of $A$, we know that $\alpha -1 \notin A$, 
i.e. , $\alpha-1 \leq \sqrt{D}$.

If $\alpha -1 = \sqrt{D}$, then $D = (\alpha-1)^2$, and D becomes a perfect square. contradiction.

Hence $\alpha -1 < \sqrt{D}$. And with $\sqrt{D}< \alpha$, we can conclude that 
$\alpha -1 < \sqrt{D} < \alpha$.

Comment: Why is it obvious that D is greater than 1? Since D belongs to the positive integers, D can equal 1 and then the proof fails

Comment: @SanjoyTheManjoy I edit my answer.